# Given a route how can we find the stating and ending GPS positions of it?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-roads-api

I need to find out the starting and ending GPS location of a given road using Google APIs. For example, how can we find out the starting and ending GPS locations of A1 Colombo-Kandy highway in Sri Lanka?

I have gone through Google Roads APIs [1] but could not find a way to get that information.

[1] https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/intro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Coordinates and Roads API

At the time being, Google Roads API doesn't have the feature of returning a polyline, nor a set of start and end coordinates for a given road.

### What can I do ?

Just because the Roads API doesn't support this feature now, it doesn't mean *this is the end of the road for you* (get my pun? :D )

You can still create a Feature Request in Google's external tracker:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/

Once there all you need to do is:

1. Go to Roads APIS
2. Click Feature Requests
3. New Issue

And it will become public, for everyone to see, including Google and its engineers !

---

Hope I helped !

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added the feature request at http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10506&q=apitype%3ARoadsAPI%20type%3AEnhancement&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars